# Duplicate Annotations for cucumber in Java BDD framework

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, bdd

Below three @Then statement coming from different step definition how to resolve this in Java.

```
@Then("User selects {string} value")
@Then("User selects {string} and verify the value are Present in the dropdown")
@Then("User selects {string} value under placements")
public void user_selectsValue(String locatorString) throws Throwable {
    locatorStr =  POC_homePageMenuItems.mainButtonDropdownNewfrmData(locatorString);
    elementclick(locatorStr);
    }
```

How to get this issue resolved, in python duplicate @Then with different step definition is allowed. How to resolve this in Java

[image]

Comment: Java only allows one of each annotation to be applied to a single method. Cucumber doesn't care about which adverbs you use. So change some of the `Then`(s) to `Given`, `When`, `And`, or `But`

Comment: It means Only one @Then can be used in for a method which defines the step definition implementation? But the function does exact same operation even it the defecation language got changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex OR grouping

```
@Then("User selects {string} (value|value under placements|and verify the value are Present in the dropdown)")
public void user_selectsValue(String locatorString, String option) throws Throwable {
```

but probably simpler to refactor to a single test phrase if the new `option` is not used/needed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using an old version of Cucumber. Since [Cucumber v5 the step definition annotations are repeatable](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/bb8f6bb1e007870b79d8d43d828be6490b6d3189/release-notes/v5.0.0.md#repeatable-annotations)